# Unregistering Addin using ESRIREGADDIN

Tags: arcgis-desktop, add-in

I am struggling to find right syntax for unregistering addin using a bat file.

path=%path%;
 "%CommonProgramFiles(x86)%"\ArcGIS\bin\ESRIRegAddIn.exe {5980f3b2-f335-47c4-bfd4-bfa181dd9c4d} /u

Problem here is that some times (very few times) it seems to work. However, most of times it doesn't.
 You can say you can simply delete the folder. However, what if the user keeps the addin in non-standard location.  However, I could install using bat file successfully.
So, I appreciate your response.

Alternatively, is there a way to programatically access additional folder locations user specified in add-in manager?
 It allows me to search for apps in those locations.

Is there any best way to tell if your add-in is installed on the user machine programmatically. With 
classic com extensibility, you can look in registry to retrieve whether an application is installed and where it is located.
 However, with add-in nothing would be added to the registry. It loads all the applications when arcmap is opened. So, what is the best approach. I opine that above two options are the way to go. Please let me know if you have any better recommendations. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also can explain how adminstrative settings in the registry could halp. I looked at documentation. It says that by adding "AddInFolders" under Settings with addin folder locations would make ArcMap load addins from this location. However, when I did it with location references to a folder in my local drive, It would not load addins in it.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what happens when it doesn't work? Error? Nothing?

Comment: I would suggest troubleshooting with procmon.exe http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx. Start it, then register and unregister the AddIn.

Comment: My most frequent reason for the EsriRegAddin.exe not to work: having an explorer window or dos shell's current directory as the AddIn Directory in `<user profile>\Documents\ArcGIS\AddIns\Desktop10.X` (I think I do this at least once a week)

Also, the EsriRegAddin.exe deals with placing/removing the AddIn in/out...`<user profile>\Documents\ArcGIS\AddIns\Desktop10.X`.  It's not going to affect the `*.esriAddIn` file itself (and you can observe what the EsriRegAddIn.exe is doing with the above-mentioned procmon.exe).

Comment: "Can you elaborate on what happens when it doesn't work? Error? Nothing?" It just throw a message "Uninstalltion Failed."

Answer (score 1):

\Documents\ArcGIS\AddIns\Desktop10.X

Go to your above path and delete the folder from the inside desktop 10.x
it will working fine.